# How can I make a view to show a user cases which are related only to their account?

Tags: community, html, customer-portal, list-view, portal

I am working on a customer community portal, and would like to setup a Cases view to embed in the webpage which shows the **contact/user who is logged** in any case for **the account they are associated with**, regardless of owner?

If I use the "My Cases" option on the view I publish to the community portal, any case they created shows up, but sometimes a customer service agent might make the case, or it might be created by Email, so we can't use that ownership function exclusively.

If there's another way to approach this, please advise, or if I can provide more information to be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Shamir

Comment: You're going to need to get the community user's contact Id so you can get their related AccountId, then query for all of the Cases related to that Account. The issue you're going to encounter though is sharing on Cases. That will likely be the most difficult issue to sort out.

Comment: Which licence type is it - Customer Community or Customer Community Plus as that changes how sharing is setup?

Comment: Hi @DaveHumm, Thanks!  The license type on the portal user is Customer Community Plus.

Comment: hi @crmprogdev - thanks!  I don't mind this being contact/contact (i.e., I am not wed to the account level) I just want a user to login and see "their" cases, regardless of how they are made.  Does that make it any easier?  Thanks!!!

Comment: With it being a Customer Community Plus license, you'll mostly likely need to use Apex Managed Sharing to share the related case records for the Account with the Customer Community User in order to do what you're asking about. That's the only way I know of off hand to do it.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev.  Can you direct me to any resources for implementing that sharing rule by best practices?  Thank you!!!!

Comment: Another option would be by code - use on the Visualforce page the without sharing notation. Then all records are available to you, and you need to decide which records to show on that page and which not (according to a field or some other logic...)

Comment: Hi @ItaiShmida, thank you!  So basically I would replace the "View" I am using on the Page Builder with a Vforce list which calls cases where (field conditions return cases I want, based on user logged in characteristics)?  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is basically what you can do, keep in mind that this is a fragile approach since you bypass the sharing rulls of the org and if you have a bug in your code you could expose data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you from experience that implementing Apex Managed Sharing in a Community Plus Org on Cases isn't something that's trivial. The solution for how best to do it is going to be unique to your particular use case. It's typically done asynchronously and not in real time for a number of reasons, most important of which is that the sharing tables will get recalculated which takes time.

In the implementations, I've done, typically when a new community user is created that meets the criteria you're going to use for sharing all the cases on an Account in your org. When the trigger fires `after insert`, typically those Id's are sent via an @future call to either a batch or queuable class where the related Accounts and all their related Cases are queried along with the sharing for them which is then granted to the new user. You can do this from within the trigger itself, but I recommend doing this asynchronously instead.

You'll also want your trigger to fire on `After Update` so the sharing is removed when a user is deactivated. Next, you'll also need a trigger on `Cases` that uses an @future call to a batchable or queuable to create the sharing for the community users when the record is created if it doesn't already exist. Since you'll likely have more than one user/account for a community, I would send every case to the batch class unless there's a reason you have not to do that.

A large part of why I recommend doing this asynchronously is because you have a Community Plus license, which means you likely have a very large number of users and will have a high volume of records that are constantly being created.

You can find more on [Apex Managed Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) in the Apex Developer Guide, including some sample code.